# Bot Framework in Facebook Messenger has error after reply with attachments

Tags: facebook, botframework

I have a Bot and I enabled the Facebook Channel. When I send a reply to the user with a carousel of Adaptive Cards...

1. I get the following error:
   `Failed with error: Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: SendActivityToUserAsync FAILED: {"error":{"message":"(#194) param name_placeholder[elements] has too few elements.","type":"OAuthException","code":194,"fbtrace_id":"EvKMopV4m\/J"}}`
2. it also shows as separate messages one after the other with buttons as even separate messages... So if I had 3 items in my carousel, then 6 items show up (3 cards + a button after each card).

I tried searching for the error message but couldn't find any answer. Can you please point me to the right direction?

This is how I make my attachment:

```
[LuisIntent("GetAllCards")]
public async Task GetAllCards(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();

        reply.Text = "Here's a few sample of cards..."; //does not appear in facebook?
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;

        if (context.ConversationData.GetValue<string>(ContextKeys.ChannelId) == "facebook")
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Here's a few sample of cards...");
        }

        using (var entities = new MyEntities())
        {
            var query = ...get stuff...                              

            var cpList = query.ToList();

            //each item is an attachment in carousel
            foreach (var cp in cpList)
            {
                var card = GetSingleCard(cp);
                var attachment = new Attachment()
                {
                    Content = card,
                    ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                    Name = cp.DisplayName //this does not actually appear anywhere on the bot when I tested
                };
                reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }

            await context.PostAsync(reply);                
}

private AdaptiveCard GetSingleCard(MyProduct cc)
{
    var card = new AdaptiveCard();

    card.Title = cc.DisplayName; //this is not shown anywhere in my bot test

    //title
    var title = new Container();
    card.Body.Add(title);

    var titleText = new TextBlock();
    title.Items.Add(titleText);
    titleText.Size = TextSize.Large;
    titleText.Text = $"**{cc.Title}**";

    var subTitleText = new TextBlock();
    title.Items.Add(subTitleText);
    subTitleText.Size = TextSize.Medium;
    subTitleText.Text = cc.SubTitle;
    subTitleText.Wrap = true;
    subTitleText.MaxLines = 1; 

    //image
    var cpImage = new AdaptiveCards.Image();
    card.Body.Add(cpImage);
    cpImage.Url = cc.ImageUrl;
    cpImage.Size = ImageSize.Large;

    //details
    var details = new FactSet();
    card.Body.Add(details);

    details.Facts.Add(new AdaptiveCards.Fact("Customer Rating", cc.Rating);
    details.Facts.Add(new AdaptiveCards.Fact("Detail A", cc.DetailA));
    details.Facts.Add(new AdaptiveCards.Fact("Detail B", cc.DetailB));


        var action = new OpenUrlAction();
        action.Url = $"https://google.com";
        action.Title = $"Read more";
        card.Actions.Add(action);


    return card;
}
```

Comment: I tried HeroCard attachments and it works fine: it shows as a carousel and no error appears after the message was sent.

Comment: Adaptive Cards are downrendered to images on Facebook Messenger.  (However, it seems that the downrendered images should be converted to Thumbnail Cards.)  Please file an issue on the BotBuilder GitHub repository for this. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new